# Angular iOS text field focus

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to open mobile keyboard when I open div with input. I tried to set the focus for input

```
 this.changeCityInput.nativeElement.focus();
```

That triggers when I click to parent div. After click on the parent div child expanding and show an input field

but it doesn't work on ios, for desktop and android it works correctly.

Also

```
document.body.ontouchend = () => {
        this.changeCityInput.nativeElement.focus();
      };
```

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.changeCityInput.nativeElement).focus();

  this.changeCityInput.nativeElement.focus();
}, 500);
```

Doesnt work.
What is the correct way to set focus on the input?

---

UPD:
On the MacOS works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focus() doesnt work with disabled button
I emulate disabled action

For default when i open div with input i focus on it, after finishing i use blur() to unfocus el